# selinux is preventing from execute access on the "binary file .so"

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, selinux, rhel8

With Rhel 8.1, I'm working on a project for middleware between the client and the server. I must launch the Apache server in this project in order for the middleware features to operate as intended.
Systemctl start httpd (hence referred to as "httpd") gives me the following error message:
The control process exited with an error code, which resulted in the job for httpd.service failing.
I went to the journalctl -xe and looked at "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for more information. I can see that selinux is restricting access to the "binary file.so" for execution.
[695109]: SELinux is restricting access to the file /etc/httpd/*.so for /usr/sbin/httpd. Run sealert -l a5e1> to get all SELinux messages.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result of `audit2allow -a`?

Comment: I tried with this audit2allow -a. but it didn't worked.
Now I have disabled the selinux .